# Ant Design Bar Chart Label size adjust programmatically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Hi I develop a stacked bar graph component using @antd/plots, now the problem is when the value is less than 15 or 10% the label of that graph is overlapping. I want to adjust the size of label of the bar when its below 15% or 20.

`

```
import { Bar, BarConfig } from "@ant-design/plots";


 export const barChart = () => {
 const chartData = [//mybarchartData]

const config:BarConfig = {
    data: chartData,
    maxBarWidth: 30,
    yField: "date",
    color: ["#4561ED", "#00D579", "#757575"],
    xField: "value",
    legend: false,
    seriesField: "status",
    isStack: true,
    label: {
      position: "middle",
      content: (item) => {
        return item.content;
      },
      style: {
        fill: "#fff",
        fontWeight: 600,
        fontSize: item?.content === 10 ? 14 : 12,
        fontFamily: "Barlow-Medium",
      },
    }
  }

 return (
  <Bar {...config} />
 )}
```

`